# How to add new elements to a jQuery object which already contains some elements

Tags: jquery

`supplieritemdata` is my object and `data` is an array. I want to add elements to the object as the checkbox checked find to be true.

My problem is that the object only holds the last values provided to it, not all the values. I want to store all the values.

```js
var supplieritemdata = {},
  data = [];

$('#tbl1 > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) {
  debugger
  // var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var ch = $(this).find(".check").prop("checked");
  if (ch) {
    supplieritemdata.SupplierId = $('#ddlsupplierdetails').val();
    supplieritemdata.ItemCategoryId = $('#ddlcategory').val();
    supplieritemdata.ItemGroupId = $('#ddlgroup').val();
    supplieritemdata.ItemId = $(this).find(".label-info").html();
  }

  data.push(supplieritemdata);
  //supplieritemdata = null;
  // $(this).prop("checked")
  // $this.find("input.name").val();
});
```

Comment: I was experimenting with supplieritemdata = null. So that it can hold the new values but this generated an error

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags. I already removed 'asp.net mvc' for a reason - it has no bearing on this client-side JS problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're amending the same *reference* to `supplieritemdata` in the iteration. This means that, although you've added that variable to the `data` array, setting it to `null`, or updating its properties will affect the instance held in the array. As such, you overwrite the properties of the single object in every iteration of the loop. This is why only the last values are shown.

To fix this you need to create a new object within each iteration of the loop.

Also note that the logic can be made more succinct by only selecting `tr` elements which have a checked checkbox (to remove the need for the `if`) and als by using `map()`. Try this:

```js
var data = $('#tbl1 > tbody  > tr:has(:checkbox:checked)').map(function() {
  return {
    SupplierId: $('#ddlsupplierdetails').val(),
    ItemCategoryId: $('#ddlcategory').val(),
    ItemGroupId: $('#ddlgroup').val(),
    ItemId: $(this).find(".label-info").html()
  }
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ddlsupplierdetails" value="ddlsupplierdetails" />
<input type="text" id="ddlcategory" value="ddlcategory" />
<input type="text" id="ddlgroup" value="ddlgroup" />
<input type="text" id="ddlsupplierdetails" value="ddlsupplierdetails" />

<table id="tbl1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="true" /></td>
      <td><span class="label-info">Foo bar 1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" /></td>
      <td><span class="label-info">Foo bar 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="check" checked="true" /></td>
      <td><span class="label-info">Foo bar 3</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Too good buddy thanks  a ton .Now can I send that data array using ajax

Comment: One more help how can i improve my jquery skills as I am a beginner to jquery.

Comment: Just keep practicing :) One thing I would suggest is to read through the documentation: https://api.jquery.com. The purpose of most of the methods are clear from their names.

Comment: using above jquery code now i want to send that data to my controller

Comment: Doing it like this but in controller it is passing null values $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 traditional:true,
                 contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: {model:JSON.stringify(data)},
                 cache: false,
                 type: "POST",
                 success: function (data) {
                     debugger
                   
                     $('#submitdata').show();

                 } });

Comment: Try removing `traditional: true`. You shouldn't need it in most cases. If that doesn't help I'd suggest starting a new question